# WiX Bootstrapper: How do I set burn variables from the command line?

Tags: command-line, wix, bootstrapper

Using WiX 3.7 and .NET 4.0.


How does one set burn variables when running a WiX bootstrapper EXE from the command line?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

First of all, the burn variables that you wish to set need to be set as `Overridable`. To do this you must include the follow namespace in your WXS: `xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension"` and if you're using Visual Studio like me you need to include `WixBalExtension.dll` in your project references. Next you need to add the following attribute to all of the burn variables that you want to set via the command line: `bal:Overridable="yes"`.


Now you can set the variables via the command line in this fashion:

```
BootstrapperSetup.exe /i /passive MyBurnVariable1=1 MyBurnVariable2=2
```

Below is an example of a WXS file that satifies all of the conditions described above:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
         xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension">

  <Bundle Name="MyProduct" Version="1.0.0" Manufacturer="MyManufacturer" UpgradeCode="PUT-UPGRADE-CODE-HERE">

    <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.HyperlinkLicense">
      <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication LicenseUrl="MyLicense.htm" ThemeFile="MyThemeFile.xml" LocalizationFile="MyLocFile.wxl" />
    </BootstrapperApplicationRef>

    <Variable Name="MyBurnVariable1" bal:Overridable="yes" Type="numeric" Value="0" />
    <Variable Name="MyBurnVariable2" bal:Overridable="yes" Type="numeric" Value="0" />

    <Chain>
      <MsiPackage Id="MyFirstMsiPackage"
                  SourceFile="first.msi"
                  InstallCondition="MyBurnVariable1 = 1" />

      <MsiPackage Id="MySecondMsiPackage"
                  SourceFile="second.msi">
        <MsiProperty Name="MY_PROPERTY" Value="[MyBurnVariable2]" />
      </MsiPackage>
    </Chain>
  </Bundle>
</Wix>
```

Comment: This is true for [WixStdBA](https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/blob/4786b1306b614b83cb96ad1b07f7597992f37126/src/ext/BalExtension/wixstdba/WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.cpp), but not for managed bootstrapper application. So it is strange that the logic for parsing and overriding variables from cmdline is not in the burn core.