# WiX Burn Bootstrapper fails immediately now that WiX has been upgraded from 3.6 to 3.11

Tags: wix, windows-installer, burn, wix3.11

I have upgraded WiX from 3.6 to **3.11**
Since then the project builds but the bootstrapper.exe burn output fails immediately, with only the following output in the logfile below:

```
[4568:5744][2021-03-25T14:48:04]i001: Burn v3.11.2.4516, Windows v10.0 (Build 19042: Service Pack 0), path: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\{AF64B619-B3D3-4801-AB2D-84F528BB2AF2}\.cr\Bootstrapper.exe
[4568:5744][2021-03-25T14:48:04]i009: Command Line: '-burn.clean.room=C:\SiteWork\Sales\Setup\Bootstrapper\bin\Release\Bootstrapper.exe -burn.filehandle.attached=604 -burn.filehandle.self=608'
[4568:5744][2021-03-25T14:48:04]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSource' to value 'C:\SiteWork\Sales\Setup\Bootstrapper\bin\Release\Bootstrapper.exe'
[4568:5744][2021-03-25T14:48:04]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSourceFolder' to value 'C:\SiteWork\Sales\Setup\Bootstrapper\bin\Release\'
[4568:5744][2021-03-25T14:48:04]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog' to value 'C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\Installer_20210325144804.log'
[4568:5744][2021-03-25T14:48:04]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleName' to value 'Installer'
[4568:5744][2021-03-25T14:48:04]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleManufacturer' to value 'Company name'
[4568:5F54][2021-03-25T14:48:04]i000: Setting version variable '聥' to value '1176.15752.0.0'
```

Any ideas what may cause this?
e.g. Are there any steps required in the upgrade from 3.6 to 3.11 other than upgrading the project references that may have caused this? I'm at a loss as to what to look for (as far as I can see there is no verbose switch like there is with a single .msi file)

[Edit]
The "Setting version variable '聥'" bit is something that has appeared since the wix (& vs2019) upgrade. Interestingly it changes each time you run the (same) bootstrapper. What it is I have no idea... e.g.

```
[4144:5C74][2021-03-26T15:27:02]i000: Setting version variable '聥' to value '848.15752.0.0'
[64C4:63A8][2021-03-26T15:27:40]i000: Setting version variable '聥' to value '776.15752.0.0'
```

Comment: Do you have your source on github? Are you using the WiX Standard Bootstrapper Application or do you use your own custom one? [Which of the available WiX variable constructs do you use](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50452114/129130)? The value for that "version variable" towards the end looks like a Unicode character? [Are you setting it via some Burn variable like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14762620/129130)? Are you dealing with any [complex localization such as this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49605354/129130)?

Comment: What encoding is your source file? UTF8? Open the file in Notepad and do a *"Save As..."* What does it say next to the *"Save"* button under *"Encoding"*?

Comment: For debugging ideas, perhaps see some other logs: [1](https://communities.vmware.com/t5/Horizon-Desktops-and-Apps/Install-failed-while-installing-VMware-Horizon-Client-4-10-0/td-p/2279414), [2](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-performance/windows-installer-service-problem/95776ee0-c42a-4870-8082-65d65f4cbe88). And the obvious thing: did you install the right Visual Studio integration? Are you on the same version of Visual Studio after your upgrade of WiX? And finally: the version field might be set as a `Type="numeric"` and end up as that weird Unicode character.

Comment: OK, spamming here, but want to add this link: https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/variable.html - what do you know `"version"` is its own type. That makes it all the more important to figure out how it is set in your case.

Comment: @SteinAsmul - not spamming at all. Many thanks for taking the time.
No source on github I'm afraid. I'l create an account and put something up. Encoding is : UTF8, Same version of VS? No. Was vs2017 now vs2019.
Now, that version variable isn't something set by us, has appeared only since the update - have added an update to the original Q.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess is you have a custom Bootstrapper Application. There's no binary compatibility in v3.x, you have to recompile the BA when you upgrade.

Comment: Sean thanks for your help. You pointed me in the right direction. I was indeed using an enhanced  Bootstrapper that is now in the standard product. After removing the custom boostrapper and some jiggery-pokery (documentation isn't great on this imho) all is now working.